# Swift error: value of type "UIButton" has no member "text"

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-playground

Here is an error I'm getting on swift when I am just trying to put a simple command.

[image]

Comment: Please post some code, I guess there is a `UILabel` / `UIButton` mismatch

Comment: Hey Just posted an image link sorry about that.

Comment: Please post text rather than an image.

Answer (score 2):

There is no text property on a UIButton. You have to use:

```
let label = UIButton()
label.setTitle(title: String?, forState:UIControlState)
```

If you check the `UIButton` documentation via option clicking the class, you can see the available functions that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

`UIButton` doesn't have a `text` property. Instead, run `setTitle:forState:` on it, like this:

`button.setTitle("My Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)`